Is there a way to keep the Apple Watch screen on?
There are a number of posts on stackoverflow from about 10 years ago asking if it's possible to keep the Apple Watch screen on programmatically and the answer at that time was no.
I'm building an app that needs the user to be informed by the Apple Watch screen for 3 1/2 minutes. When Xcode loads it onto the watch, it stays on for that time. But if I start the app from the watch as a normal user, after 15 seconds it dims and the screen stops updating.
At present is there any way or strategy to have the screen on without dimming and stopping updating for 3 1/2 minutes?
